# Is it possible to import Photoshop PSD to Expression Blend to fill in an existing layout structure?

Tags: silverlight, layout, import, expression-blend, photoshop

I need to create a fairly complicated layout for a widget in Expression Blend, with the visual design not yet set to stone, while having fairly refined functional wireframes.

So I started to lay out the UI controls and choosing layout structures based on the wireframes, but as far as I have seen so far while experimenting, PSD files will be imported using their internal layer structure.

What is the best workflow to be able to import / replace elements, without the need to redo everything bit by bit on every import? Expression Blend's PSD importer is very good in converting vector layers with simple layer effects into Blend native vector artwork and effects, but what's the best way of getting these into the right place in the existing layout structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked a bit more with Expression Blend it seems that it's far from being possible.

On import Blend will just create a completely new layout structure in your root element and try to reflect the PSD structure inside. It also does it in an annoying way too, making canvases out of layer groups (which you'll almost probably need to turn to grids and reposition elements inside manually) and it places your vector paths offset with arbitrary numbers inside, so you'll have to tend it manually if you want anything else than a completely static, absolute layout.

The best workflow I could come up with so far is to create the layout structure you want and paste in bits from the imported structure by hand. Dreadful, but at least if you use layer effects sparingly in Photoshop and stick to vector paths, Blend will do a good job of converting them to paths. Although that's beyond me why can't it turn rectangle paths into native rectangles, so you'll have to do that manually too.

Oh wait, almost forgot the best part, for any non trivial vector shape, make sure you check it after import with the direct selection tool as Blend sometimes puts in a lot of extra control points for no apparent reason!